# Delete specific line from file

Tags: c++, line, fstream

I'm trying to delete a specific line by id from a file in C++ and here is my code:

```
void deleteRow()
{
    ifstream inDb("files/students.dat", ios::in);
    if(!inDb)
    {
        cerr << "File could no be opened!\n";
    }

    cout << countRowsOfDb() << " records." << endl;

    Student *studentsArray[countRowsOfDb()];

    int n = 0;

    while(inDb >> id >> name >> grade >> points >> type)
    {
        studentsArray[n] = new Student(id, name, grade, points, type);
        n++;
    }

    inDb.close();

    for(int i = 0; i < countRowsOfDb(); i++)
    {
        cout << studentsArray[i]->id << " " << studentsArray[i]->name << " " << studentsArray[i]->grade << " "
             << studentsArray[i]->points << " " << studentsArray[i]->type << "\n";
    }

    cout << "\nWhich one you would like to delete? Enter an id: ";

    string term;
    cin >> term;

    ofstream outDb("files/students.dat", ios::out);
    if(!outDb)
    {
        cerr << "File could no be opened!\n";
    }


    for(int i = 0; i < countRowsOfDb(); i++)
    {
        if(studentsArray[i]->id != term)
        {
                outDb << studentsArray[i]->id << " " << studentsArray[i]->name << " " << studentsArray[i]->grade << " "
                      << studentsArray[i]->points << " " << studentsArray[i]->type << "\n";
        }
    }

    outDb.close();

    cout << "\nObject deleted!\n";
}
```

I create a input file stream and then get all the rows, make it array of objects and show them on the screen then ask which one to delete by typing an id, and when I type the id, I'm trying to put all these elements of the array only without the element with same id, but it don't works, after that there is nothing in the file. Any ideas?

Comment: What are the values of studentsArray[i]->id and term on the row you expect to delete?

Comment: You have a memory leak from not `delete`ing each element of your array. Try `std::vector`.

Comment: `Student *studentsArray[countRowsOfDb()];` How does this compile? Shouldn't array size be a compile time constant?

Comment: studentsArray[i]->id, and term are strings and if they are the same the element with that id will be ignored

Comment: countRowsOfDb() is function that returns int and it cant be constant because the rows can be deleted or added anytime.. ?

Comment: @TadeuszKopec, Yes, that is not standard C++. You probably want a `Student *studentsArray = new Student [countRowsOfDb()];` Be sure to `delete[]` that one, though. Vectors really do solve all of the issues here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's in `countRowsOfDb()`?  If it opens the file and counts the lines
in it (and I don't know what else it could do), then it's not going to
find a lot in the final loop, since the creation of the ostream with the
same name will have emptied the file.

More generally, this is a very inefficient way of doing things (and 
could easily fail if there were an error in the format of the file).
The best way to handle this is to use an `std::vector<Student>`, with:

```
studentVector.push_back( Student( id, name, grade, points, type ) );
```

in the input loop.  In all later loops, `studentVector.size()` gives the
number of entries, or you can use the iterators.

Even better would be to use `std::getline` on the
input, then initialize an `std::istringstream` to parse each line.  This
will catch input format errors much more reliably.  Something like:

```
std::string line;
int lineNumber = 0;
while ( std::getline( inDb, line ) ) {
    ++ lineNumber;
    std::istringstream data( line );
    if ( data >> id >> name >> grade >> points >> type ) {
        studentVector.push_back( Student( id, name, grade, points, type ) );
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Format error in lne " << lineNumber << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Also, it is generally a better idea to write to separate file, then
rename it *after* having verified that the write worked, i.e.:

```
std::ofstream outDb( "files/students.dat.new" );
//  Do output...
outDb.close();
if ( outDb ) {
    remove( "files/students.dat" );
    rename( "files/students.dat.new", "files/students.dat" );
} else {
    std::cerr << "Write error on output" << std::endl;
}
```

And of course, any write error should result in a return of
`EXIT_FAILURE` from `main`.  (This is one case where a global variable
or a singleton is justified—keeping track of the return code.)

Answer (score 0):

I made it to work by adding a new function that replays the content so now the code is:

```
void deleteRow()
{
    ifstream inDb("files/students.dat", ios::in);
    if(!inDb)
    {
        cerr << "File could no be opened!\n";
    }

    cout << countRowsOfDb() << " records." << endl;

    Student *studentsArray[countRowsOfDb()];

    int n = 0;

    while(inDb >> id >> name >> grade >> points >> type)
    {
        studentsArray[n] = new Student(id, name, grade, points, type);
        n++;
    }

    inDb.close();

    for(int i = 0; i < countRowsOfDb(); i++)
    {
        cout << studentsArray[i]->id << " " << studentsArray[i]->name << " " << studentsArray[i]->grade << " "
             << studentsArray[i]->points << " " << studentsArray[i]->type << "\n";
    }

    cout << "\nWhich one you would like to delete? Enter an id: ";

    string term;
    cin >> term;

    for(int i = 0; i < countRowsOfDb(); i++)
    {
        if(studentsArray[i]->id != term)
        {
            Student studentTemp(studentsArray[i]->id, studentsArray[i]->name, studentsArray[i]->grade, studentsArray[i]->points, studentsArray[i]->type);
            replaceRow(studentTemp);
        }
    }

    cout << "\nObject deleted!\n";
}
```

and the replace function is:

```
void replaceRow(Student student)
{
    ofstream outDb("files/students.dat", ios::out);
    if(!outDb)
    {
        cerr << "File could no be opened!\n";
    }

    outDb << student.getId() << ' ' << student.getName() << ' ' << student.getGrade()
          << ' ' << student.getPoints() << ' ' << student.getType() << endl;

    outDb.close();
}
```

Comment: How does this work?  Every time you open `"files/students.dat" in `replaceRow`, you truncate the file.  So only the last call to `replaceRow` should be present after you run your program.

Comment: @JamesKanze can i ask you more things about whole program?

Comment: i made it now and change some stuffs and it works without a vector.. but for future programs because now this isn't important i want to ask you just to explain how you will create a program that should: add line in the file, edit, delete and the line should be object of class Student and this class to have variables: id, name, grade, points, type (where points and type are for competition info)

Comment: i want to learn some principles or best practices for creating program like this.. or can you recommend me a book or something ? :]

Comment: If the data fit into memory, the best solution is to read them into a vector, do the changes on the vector, and then write them out---to a temporary file first, then deleting the original and renaming the temporary (after having closed the temporary and verified that there are no errors).  Also, as long as you are dealing with "data" (no real behavior), you should use value semantics; a vector of `Student`, and not of `Student*`.

Comment: Both the Langer and Kreft and the Josuttis are excellent references.  Regretfully, however, I'm not aware of any good tutorial concerning the iostreams.

Comment: ok i will try it with vectors, and i wasn't asking only for iostreams i asked for c++ language :]